# Unable to catch form submit with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems like it should be simple and as far as I can tell I am doing this like many other examples on the web. I have also tried this with IE and Chrome and can not get this to work. I also confirm some functionality by putting alert after the jQuery(function($){.... this worked just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm pulling my hair out.

In the Body of my page:

```
    <div id="chat"></div>
    <form id="send-message" action="">
        <input size="35" id="message"></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){

            var socket = io.connect();
            var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
            var $messageBox = $('#message');
            var $chat = $('#chat');

            $messageForm.submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("jQuery Loaded.");
                socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val());
                $messageBox.val('');
            });

            socket.on('new message', function(data){
                $chat.append(data + '<br />');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/LXAPp/ . Probably, you are getting js error comes from another part of your code. Check your console if any error exists

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Comment: When I submit the form the event handler function is not being called.

Comment: @Hüseyin BABAL The console helped, I'm new to javascript, thanks for the advice. It looks like the problem is that io is not defined so the script is stopping there.

Comment: This means, `scoket.io` not found. Be sure socket.io path is correct. If you have non-node.js project, you need to specify full path of `scoket.io`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The script failed at the var socket = io.connect(); because io was not defined. io was not defined because I put scr not src in the include for the script that defines it.